Powershell Crashes upon launch
Long-time issue, haven't gotten anywhere. Windows Server 2019 Datacenter (1809 - OS Build 17763.5576), Enterprise environment with 14 physical servers, all same OS. When I launch powershell in this env, the window opens for a brief moment (can't even read what's there) and then closes. It doesn't generate any event logs for the error.
If I run "powershell" from CMD I get "Starting the CLR failed with HRESULT 80070005." Also no event logs generated from this. All research on that error and PowerShell has led nowhere. of note: if I try to uninstall PowerShell feature in windows it fails.
i have run all patches, all DISM fixes under the sun (including downloading/mounting a fresh ISO and running the repair with this as the source); dism has said repair successful a few times, but no change with PowerShell. Bluescreenview shows no minidumps.
Let me know what other details could be helpful.

Why are you running PowerShell from a Command Prompt instead of just launching a PowerShell prompt directly? 80070005 is an access denied error.  Has these systems always had this problem or did only recently start to exhibit these problems?

0x80070005 is an "Access Denied" error. You're trying to do something that you don't have the rights for.

@Ramhound Context may indicate when OP opened PS normally the window went away too quickly for them to see any messages, and so they opened in CMD and was then able to see the error. Also, OP notes it is a "long time issue".

@music2myear - "long time issue" does indicate if it used to work and just broke or if it never worked. For all I know it's not suppose to work per their security polices.

OP, the fact this is happening on multiple servers indicates it is likely an applied permissions/policy issue, rather than a software issue with the servers themselves. What permissions does your account have on these servers? Am I correct to assume you are IT and at least somewhat responsible for the servers? What happens when another user/different account is used to run PS?

@Ramhound Yea, it's almost certainly an image or policy issue, given the fact the behavior is the same on multiple servers.

Thank you all for the comments.  I was only using CMD as a test and to see any kind of error.  I have tried other domain admin users, as well as creating new local admin users and the behavior is the same across the board.  I've also run gpresult and reviewed GPOs, so far I haven't found one that could be the culprit.  I am L3 IT but this is a new environment for our team (MSP) so I don't know if it ever worked (part of the difficulty perhaps).

This might be unreated but KB5035849 had a know issue with LSASS.  KB5037425 fixes that problem but I would install KB5036896 instead. If you don't know if it ever worked then you need to find somebody who knows if it worked.  If it never worked it's possible it's not suppose to work.

@Ramhound KB5036896 is already installed.  Trust me I wish I had a way to talk to someone who knows, but it's the nature of our company - we acquired this client/network and have no contact with previous IT folks.

Check that PowerShell is not disabled in Group Policies:

Open GPO editor.
Check for a policy under User Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Software Restriction Policies that disallows PowerShell, and, if it exists, remove it.

If you wish, it can be enabled for Administrators only.

Double-checked this both in local policy and group policy, no software restriction is in place.  Good thought.
